# Abaqus automatically reload modules

Tags: python, abaqus

As the title says: is there an option to automatically reload modules on every run? Right now I always have to press the reload modules button and sometimes I forget it causing me to search for hours after a solved bug.

I searched in the manual, but couldn't find anything.

EDIT: Since Abaqus still uses python 2.x, you can use the built-in function reload, which will also reload the modules. However I didn't find an Abaqus setting to do the same.

Comment: Can't you just append the top or bottom of your script with `reload(...)`?

Comment: yes indeed, I realised it after asking the question. That's why I added the *EDIT. However I wanted to let the question stand for other people like me having the same issue that are not familiar with the reload function.